# Super Activity controller which can control the overall app

Tags: android, android-activity

Recently I was developing an app that plays a music playing in the background all through the app. And the music should pause whenever it goes to background or the screen gets locked. For that, I had to handle write an `onPause()` and an `onResume()` in every activity for the music to pause when it goes to background and to resume when it back to the main view. I was wondering is there was a way where the android life cycle can be controlled from one **Super Activity** do that I don't need to use onPause and onResume in every activity.

Comment: I am trying to get all the possible ways in which the above requirement can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a baseActivity and reuse the code by making all other activities extend baseActivity.

Comment: Thanks! @Curious Main. Is there any other way! Or is this the only way that could be done?

Comment: There should be other ways - this is the only one I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to do this things (playing music) in a service. Take a look to services in android [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#java). After you bind your service, you can play your music or stop it whenever you want. For screen lock situation, declare a broadcast receiver and then register it (In your service class). Take a look to broadcast receivers [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). As soon as your screen get locked, your receiver will be fired and you can stop music in receiver.

Comment: And I wanna resume the music when it Activity is back on. Is that possible with the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 1):

there are `@Override` methods for this kind of apps

first extend `Application`   and the you can use methods like this

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
   Log.e("","onActivityCreated:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
  }

  public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
   Log.e("","onActivityDestroyed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
  }

  public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
   Log.e("","onActivityPaused:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
  }

  public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
   Log.e("","onActivityResumed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
  }
```

they wont be call when you move from one activity to another but will be called when you press the home button or destroy the app from recents

here i am attaching some sites for more help
[link 1](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-use-activitylifecyclecallbacks.html)
[link 2](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-detect-android-application-open-and-close-background-and-foreground-events-1b4713784b57)

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin. This looks like a simple and a right fit for my app.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tested your code and noticed that the function onActivityPaused() and onActivityResumed() is called everytime I move between activity. Isn't it suppose to work only during the home button press or screen lock.